# $facebook->getUser() returns zero

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've a problem with the Facebook PHP API. here is my code:

```
<?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'MY_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'MY_SECRET'
));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();
if ($uid) {
    try{
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (Exception $e){
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

if (!$uid) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(  
        'next' =>   'http://www/mywebsite.com', 
        'redirect_uri' =>   'http://www/mywebsite.com', 
        'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location'
    ));

    echo '<a href="'.$login_url.'">TEST TO CONNECT</a>';
} else {
    print_r($user);
}
```

I keep having the line TEST TO CONNECT so it looks like $facebook->getUser(); always returns 0. Any idea?

Thank you for your help

Comment: instead of "if (!$uid)" you could just use "else"...just a hint

Answer (score 1):

Can you see any errors? Are you being taken to the login page and returned back? Or is it all fine?

The error in your code seems to be under the part `if (!$uid)` where you then generate the login url.

I dont really find what `'next' =>   'http://www/mywebsite.com',` does there.

Try using this :

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                array(
                   'scope'         => 'publish_stream,read_friendlists,user_photos',
                   'redirect_uri'  => $redirecturi
                )
            );
```

And also, dont forget to include the Facebook PHP SDK File.

`require_once("facebook.php");//or full location if the file is placed elsewhere.`

Answer (score 0):

If that is your full code, then there is one major problem: You did not include the facebook class at the beginning:

```
include 'Facebook.php';
```

Also make sure that your App ID and App Secret are correct. And use "publish_actions" instead of "publish_stream".

If that does not help, debug. facebook usually tells you what´s wrong.

Comment: I figured it out. xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" was missing :)
Thanks for your help

Comment: for login with php, the namespace should be irrelevant...also, the correct namespace is this one now: <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. I searched all over the internet, visited blogs, forums but everything in vain. So, I decided to use JS SDK of facebook instead of PHP SDK. When I did this, JS SDK extended the login process by saying that my account was accessed from some other browser. This extended display was not appearing from php sdk side. I thought I should revert back and try using the PHP SDK again ... and bamn it worked.

So basically its not the error of your code rather the login process of fb gives rise to this error. You have two option : i) Either ask your friend to participate in test login ii) Use js sdk