# Facebook getUser() return 0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

every time i get 0 after getting permission from Facebook.where do i wrong ? and what is getAccessToken() ??

i had a working script but i lost it, anyone have a working script ?

This is my code:

> ```
> <?PHP
> include_once "src/facebook.php";
>
>
> $app_id       = "525085840939034";
> $app_secret   = "80b8a0095f0af94c1329c7142f11a68d";
> $site_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Facebook/index.php';
>
>
>
>
> $facebook = new Facebook(array(
>   'appId'     => $app_id,
>   'secret'    => $app_secret,
>   'cookie' => TRUE
>   ));
>
> $user = $facebook->getUser();
>
> if($user){
>   // Get logout URL
>   $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
> }else{
>   // Get login URL
>   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
>       'scope'         => 'read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos',
>       'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
>       ));
> }
>
>
> echo $user;
>
> ?>
> ```

```
<a href="<?=$loginUrl?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the user you need to use [`getUser`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/) which is missing in your code. It should be as

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'     => $app_id,
  'secret'    => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => TRUE
  ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){
  // Get logout URL
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
  // Get login URL
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
      'scope'         => 'read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos',
      'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
      ));
}
```

[`getAccessToken()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/) will give you the current access token being used by the SDK.

Comment: sory, i had $user = $facebook->getUser(); part forget to type here.

Comment: well this could happen for various reason in the settings. You may check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039869/facebook-php-sdk-uid-facebook-getuser-always-returns-0  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793058/solvedfacebook-php-sdk-getuser-return-always-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375576/facebook-getuser-returns-zero http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168764/facebook-getuser-always-returns-0-php-sdk-3-1-1